# Include BibTeX contents in a listings block

Tags: bibtex, listings, inline

I am trying to include the literal contents of a BibTeX file in my LaTeX document using the `listings` package but am running into an issue.

As BibTeX does not appear to be natively supported (though TeX and BibTeX are), I have had to define [the language syntax highlighting](https://svn.kwarc.info/repos/arXMLiv/trunk/sty/bibtex.sty):

```
 \lstdefinelanguage{BibTeX}
  {otherkeywords={%
      @article,@book,@collectedbook,@conference,@electronic,@ieeetranbstctl,%
      @inbook,@incollectedbook,@incollection,@injournal,@inproceedings,%
      @manual,@mastersthesis,@misc,@patent,@periodical,@phdthesis,@preamble,%
      @proceedings,@standard,@string,@techreport,@unpublished%
      },%
    sensitive=false,
    morecomment=[s]{@comment}
  }[keywords,comments]
```

To include a .bib file, I am using:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\lstinputlisting[language={BibTeX}]{mybibtex.txt}
\caption{Check out by BibTeX contents!}
\label{fig:bibtex}
\end{figure}
```

...but am told:

```
! Undefined control sequence.\lst@OutputToken...lst@CheckMerge {\lst@thestyle{\lst@FontAdjust \setbox \... @article
```

...when I compile the LaTeX.

How do I include the contents of .bib file in my document? I am using Texmaker 3.1.

**Minimum Working Example**

*mwe.tex*

```
\documentclass{article}            
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\lstset{%
 backgroundcolor=\color{red},
 basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,
 breaklines = true
}%

\lstdefinelanguage{BibTeX}
  {otherkeywords={%
      @article
      },%
    sensitive=false,
    morecomment=[s]{@comment}
  }[keywords,comments]


\begin{document}
%\lstinputlisting[language={BibTeX}]{mwe.bib} % problematic line
\lstinputlisting{mwe.bib}

\end{document}
```

*mwe.bib*

```
@article{myarticle ,
language = {English},
title = {MWE title},
abstract = {MWE abstract},
keywords = {MWE;Stack Overflow;BibTeX},
}
```

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. I have tried the snippet and it does not show that problem (but I don't get syntax highlight either).

Comment: I have added as close to an MWE as I could with the problematic line commented out. It seems that applying my language definition causes the compiler issue but I still don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrarily to what one might think reading the documentation, those keywords seem to want `keywords`, rather than `otherkeywords`; there is another glitch: `morecomment=[s]...` wants *two* arguments.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{myarticle,
  language = {English},
  title = {MWE title},
  abstract = {MWE abstract},
  keywords = {MWE;Stack Overflow;BibTeX},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{%
 backgroundcolor=\color[gray]{.85},
 basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
 breaklines = true,
 keywordstyle=\color{red!75},
 columns=fullflexible,
}%

\lstdefinelanguage{BibTeX}
  {keywords={%
      @article,@book,@collectedbook,@conference,@electronic,@ieeetranbstctl,%
      @inbook,@incollectedbook,@incollection,@injournal,@inproceedings,%
      @manual,@mastersthesis,@misc,@patent,@periodical,@phdthesis,@preamble,%
      @proceedings,@standard,@string,@techreport,@unpublished%
      },
   comment=[l][\itshape]{@comment},
   sensitive=false,
  }

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[language=BibTeX]{\jobname.bib}

\end{document}
```

[image]